# vagrant checksum error while installing linux-mint xfce desktop

Tags: vagrant, linux-mint, vagrantfile, xfce

VagrantFile:

```
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "zenshade/mint64-xfce-20"
  config.vm.box_version = "1.0.0"
  config.vm.hostname="master1"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
      vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
        vb.memory = 1500
        vb.cpus = 2
        vb.name = "kube-master1"
        if !File.exist?("disk/master1.vdi")
          vb.customize [
            'createhd', 
            '--filename', 'disk/master1', 
            '--format', 'VDI', 
            '--size', 20000
            ] 
        end
  end
end
```

After running I am getting following error:

```
The checksum of the downloaded box did not match the expected
value. Please verify that you have the proper URL setup and that
you're downloading the proper file.

Expected: 5cdefeacdd0259ea666f1112211af306  package.box
Received: 5cdefeacdd0259ea666f1112211af306
```

I am not getting the reson behind the checksum error. I am trying to setup linux mint xfce desktop. How can I match the checksum value?

Answer (score 0):

for this problem i think we have only one solution that update the checksum of your package  on vagrant cloud to the Expected checksum.

Expected: 5cdefeacdd0259ea666f1112211af306  package.box
Received: 5cdefeacdd0259ea666f1112211af306